# How to specify ">" in redis-py

Tags: python, redis

I'm looking at this in the [redis stream documentation](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro), which says:

> It is time to try reading something using the consumer group:
>
> ```
> > XREADGROUP GROUP mygroup Alice COUNT 1 STREAMS mystream >
> 1) 1) "mystream"
>    2) 1) 1) 1526569495631-0
>          2) 1) "message"
>             2) "apple"
> ```
>
> XREADGROUP replies are just like XREAD replies. Note however the GROUP
>     provided above, it states that I want to
>   read from the stream using the consumer group mygroup and I'm the
>   consumer Alice. Every time a consumer performs an operation with a
>   consumer group, it must specify its name uniquely identifying this
>   consumer inside the group.
>
> There is another very important detail in the command line above,
>   after the mandatory STREAMS option the ID requested for the key
>   mystream is the special ID >. This special ID is only valid in the
>   context of consumer groups, and it means: messages never delivered to
>   other consumers so far.

I am trying to specify the ">" parameter in redis-py.

When I look at the documentation [here](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/redis/client.html#Redis.xreadgroup), I don't see any parameter in streams that seems to let me do this.  Specifically, I'm trying:

```
>>> r.xreadgroup(mygroupname,myconsumer,{mystream : ">"},1)
[] # oh no, empty. WHY?!
# 
# even though
>>> r.xread({mystream: '1561950326849-0'}, count=1)
[[b'stuff-returned-successfully.]]
```

What am I missing? Why can't I specify a ">" to indicate unseen messages?

Answer (score 1):

You had a mistaken assumption in this question that you had /unseen/ messages.  That command should work, but will not if you have already seen all the messages once.

Try

```
# make sure you have not seen anything in your stream by resetting last seen to 0
>>> r.xgroup_setid(mystream,mygroupname,0) # RESET ALL
```

Now

```
r.xreadgroup(mygroupname,myconsumer,{mystream : ">"},1)
```

works fine.